# Why does my discord role return undefined?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Okay so I have some basic code that creates a role and it finds it, I tried getting the id from the const as it is saved or from finding it but it is null 100% of the time, the role is created and IDK the problem.

```js
const roleowo = msg.guild.createRole({ name: channelname, color: 'YELLOW' }).then((role) => {msg.member.addRole(role);}).catch(console.error);
                let myRole = msg.guild.roles.get(roleowo);

                msg.guild.createChannel(channelname, {
                type: 'voice',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                  {
                    id: 'this is an actual id but I will not show it here I am dumb',
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                  },
                    {
                      id: myRole.id,
                      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    }
                  ]
                });
```

Comment: If your code is going to be executable, please define all variables

Answer (score 2):

`roleowo` is equal to a `Promise<Role>`. You need to put all of your code inside of the `.then()`

```
msg.guild.createRole({ name: channelname, color: 'YELLOW' })
    .then((role) => {
        msg.member.addRole(role);
        
        msg.guild.createChannel(channelname, {
            type: 'voice',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: 'this is an actual id but I will not show it here I am dumb',
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: role.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                }
            ]
        });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```